# How to supply and demand analysis for crude oil

Tags: investing, trading, commodities, value-investing

Hi I'm trying to forecast the price of crude oil (WTI) and based on that either go long or short crude oil. When investing/trading stocks I normally do dcf analysises or so on the company to get the intrinsic value of the company and then I use technicals to trade. Now I'm trying to do the same for crude oil and I've seen that I need to analyse the supply and demand for oil and then forecast that to forecast the oil price. How would I do a supply and demand analysis for crude oil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a simple answer since "crude oil" is a very broad spectrum.

From the supply side, oil is produced in multiple locations across the globe, and with varying properties (e.g. "sour" crude contains more sulfur and thus is cheaper, but requires special equipment to be usable to refineries. It can also be traded between countries, so supply can come from international sources as well. That said, you could look at statistics like daily oil production and/or strategic reserve levels to get some sense of "supply" levels.

From the demand side, it's even more complex since crude oil is used in a variety of ways. The largest use is to produce gasoline, and as mentioned before refineries can take varying blends of oil. Most other petroleum products are by-products of the refining process, buy gasoline usage is a decent (but not complete) indicator of oil demand. So you might look at gasoline usage like the ones provided by the [EIA](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/gasoline/use-of-gasoline.php)

There are services out there that do all of this work and provide aggregate supply/demand stats,

Answer (score 1):

The price is vulnerable to the inscrutable politics of Saudi Arabia.  In 2016 they defied all expectations of $100 to $85 WTI oil in order to put the shale oil industry out of business, taking the price down to $24.  And still they failed to put the shale oilers out of business.  Now they are driving the price down to hurt Russia?  With out-of-left-field actions like this there is no way to model the price of oil.  It's gambling, like roulette.

Answer (score -3):

> How would I do a supply and demand analysis for crude oil?

List the reasons you might think oil price is going up.

List the reasons you might think oil price is going down.

I think you'll find it's way too hard to calculate a "fair value" for a barrel of oil. Oil is a commodity, and as such, its price is extremely volatile. Thus, by predicting its price, you will be right 50% of the time and wrong 50% of the time.

My take on the matter:

- Burning oil emits greenhouse gases, so it must stop.
- There will be a huge tax on carbon dioxide sooner or later.
- The huge tax will bump the oil *consumer* price up so high that nobody is willing to pay it.
- The huge tax will cause the oil *producer* price to crash so low that nobody is willing to produce it.
- Oil production, and equivalently, oil consumption, will eventually stop. Whatever little oil is consumed will be produced from renewable sources.

If trading derivatives related to oil, you'd better be sure whether it's the *producer* price or *consumer* price you're doing your betting on.

I would not buy oil-producing stocks.

I would also not buy oil-consuming stocks.

I would buy renewable energy technology stocks.

Comment: What you have done is present a very subjective decision making framework. Nothing above has relates to performing supply demand analysis.